# Angular filter not returning back full list after search

Tags: angular, search, filter, angular-material, filtering

I have a searchbox that filter Mat Cards but when ever the user done searching, all the mat cards are not showing anymore.

For example, I have a bunch of cards and the user search "John Card", it filter John Card but when the user remove his input, only John Card stuck there and it's doesn't show the full mat cards anymore.

TS file

```
  searchText:string;
  workspaces: Workspace[] = [];

    this.loading = true;
    this.workspaceService.getPublicWorkspaces().pipe(takeUntil(this.death$)).subscribe((workspaces) =>{

    this.workspaces = workspaces;

    this.showColumn = false;
    this.loading = false;
    }, ()=>this.loading = false)
}
  searchTextChanged(searchText){
    //return array of workspace only having search text in their names
     this.workspaces = this.workspaces.filter(pubws=>pubws.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase().trim()));
   }
```

HTML

```
<input matInput [formControl]="inputCtrl" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="searchTextChanged($event)" placeholder="Search" class="input">

<mc-workspace-card-list [workspaces] = "workspaces" [editable] = "false"></mc-workspace-card-list>
```

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because u override your model here

```
this.workspaces = this.workspaces.filter(pubws=>pubws.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase().trim()));
```

in html  change your input to

```
<input matInput [formControl]="inputCtrl" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="searchTextChanged()" placeholder="Search" class="input">
```

initialize your string  after decleration

```
searchText:string="";
```

create one more temp_element

```
workspacesTemp: Workspace[] = [];
```

and fill both of them

```
 this.workspaces = workspaces;
 this.workspacesTemp = workspaces;
```

filter it with this temp

```
searchTextChanged(){
    var search=this.searchText;
    if(search==""){this.workspaces=this.workspacesTemp;}
     this.workspaces = this.workspacesTemp.filter(pubws=>pubws.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase().trim()));
   }
```

Comment: Thank for this but some reason it's not filtering anymore. I also change to both workspace and worspacesTemp in the HTML but it's not filtering anymore.

Comment: did u fill the workspacesTemp also when u get data from the service ?

Comment: Can u share your all components in your question then i can see the problem part ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but I did exactly you told me and sadly it didn't filter anymore. I edit my post and included the whole Typescript code if you don't mind checking.

Comment: I edited my answer u can edit due to my answer again ?